# how to implement levenberg marquardt in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Levenberg Marquardt algorithm in Keras which is originally implemented in MATLAB. I have searched so many sites but I haven't found anything about it? how can I Implement this algorithm?

Comment: I suggest you ask your question on other channels, like data science channel or stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: do you have any news on this? I'm trying to do the same